# CMake target_link_options LINKER syntax

Tags: c++, cmake

Since CMake 3.13, [target_link_options](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/command/target_link_options.html) exists that adds "options to the link step".

Near the bottom of that page it says:

> To pass options to the linker tool, each compiler driver has its own syntax. The `LINKER:` prefix and `,` separator can be used to specify, in a portable way, options to pass to the linker tool

Could someone give an example of how you would use `target_link_options()` with the `LINKER:` helper?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: There's an example at the bottom of the link you provided.  Did that not work for you?

Comment: @StephenNewell (apologies for not putting this in the question) if I wanted to pass something like "-wl,--no-as-needed" using that how would I do it using that? I cannot test right now but are you saying something like "LINKER:--no-as-needed" would work? I tried "LINKER:-Wl,--no-as-needed" as an item to target_link_options and that did not work.

Comment: You pass `-Wl,--no-as-needed` to gcc, then gcc passes `--no-as-needed` to the linker. The linker option is `--no-as-needed`, so you should do `LINKER:--no-as-needed`.

Comment: _facepalms_ Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

The idea is to put all linker options as a string of comma-separated items prepended by 'LINKER:'. Say I have these set of flags which I use with the compiler invocation (gcc):

```
-Wl,--gc-sections,-Tbootloader.ld,-Map=bootloader.map
```

Then cmake portion should look like.

```
...
add_executable(bootloader ${SRC})
target_link_options(bootloader PUBLIC "LINKER:--gc-sections,-Tbootloader.ld,-Map=bootloader.map") 
...
```